# How to plot these two time-series of different years on the same plot, with the same resolution?

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe, matplotlib, time-series

I am trying to plot two years worth of data, contained in different data frames, on the same graph. The images are below.[A plot of the current separate years of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xswmh.png)

```
#Sets the size of the figure in the notebook
%pylab inline
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (25, 15)


#Plots the figure, configures settings about the plot
plt.plot(df['date_time'],df['WTMP','degC'])
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())

#fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=15) 
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize = 15)

#Size of ticks
plt.tick_params(direction='out', length=10, width=2,)

#X and Y labels
plt.xlabel('Time',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('WTMP (degC)',fontsize=18)

plt.show()

#Second Plot

plt.plot(df2['date_time'],df2['WTMP','degC'],color = 'red')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())

plt.show()
```

How can I show these two plots in the exact same way on the same graph? I have tried using a pivot table with the following line

```
piv = pd.pivot_table(result, index=['month'],columns=['year'], values=
['WTMP'])
```

which works, but it is smoothed out and I don't get the same day to day resolution as above.

Comment: Seems you just need to remove `plt.show()` in between the plotting commands.

Comment: When I do that, I get the data over 2 years. instead of overlaying on top of eachother, it plots continuously from the beginning of 2014 to the end of 2015

Comment: Sure. If you want to show the 2015 data as if it was from 2014 you need to substract one year from it.